# Magento 2 : How to Return the Collection from afterload

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, uicomponent, resource-model

I have implemented this **jquerytokenizer in Ui Component** form shown in the below image.
     [image]

It works well , the data is saved accurately- but when I go to edit a saved record this field is empty without the saved tags.

> To serve the purpose I fetched the tags in afterload

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

    use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
    use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
    use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
    use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context;
    use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager;


    class Article extends AbstractDb
    {

    protected $_store = null;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $entityManager;


    protected $metadataPool;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        $connectionName = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_module', 'articles_id');
    }


    protected function _afterLoad(AbstractModel $product)
    {
        $articleId = $product->getId();
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
             $select = $connection->select()->from(['tag_table_name' => 'tag_table_name'])
                 ->where('tag_table_name.' . 'articles_id' . ' IN (?)', $articleId);
             $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
             //print_r($result);exit;

        return parent::_afterLoad($product);
    }  
}
```

> When I echo $result the result is

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [articles_id] => 33
        [tag_names] => asdfasdf
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [articles_id] => 33
        [tag_names] => adfasdfsad
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [articles_id] => 33
        [tag_names] => fsdafdsafsdaf
    )

   )
```

> My Ui Component form field is :

```
<field name="tag_names">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">   
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/tags</item>

                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>

                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/tags</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Article Tags</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
```

> And the custom filed html is :

```
<select multiple class="admin__control-multiselect" data-bind="
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    id: uid,

    disabled: disabled,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    placeholder: placeholder
},
hasFocus: focused,

selectedOptions: value,
optionsValue: 'label',
optionsText: 'label',
modtaggee: true"
/>
```

Can any one figure out where I am going wrong or propose a solution. Thanks in Advance.